# Look Back function in Journey Builders

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Good morning,

I want to build a Journey with the following behaviour:

Send 10 emails and, after send the last email, if the contact doesn't fulfill a condition, loop back his journey in order to send him the first email again. I have tried to use a Join Activity but the system doesn't allow me to do that.

Is there a way to built the journey as I want?

Thank you,
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create loops in Journey Builder.

A simple solution would be to just repeat the Email activity after the decision split which checks if the customer fulfills your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the contacts reenter the journey, depending on your use case.